# How to solve Fortify 19.1 low memory error?

Tags: fortify, fortify-source, sourceanalyser

I'm using fortify to scan python and php code base. The sourceanalyzer complains about insufficient memory. I have 8 GB now. I'm planning to upgrade to 16 GB.

My question is should I use the option -Xmx after the upgrade. The docs say fortify makes optimal memory allocation for itself, so does using the -Xmx bring in better performance than default memory allocation (-autoheap)

**Edit**

After update to 32 GB RAM fortify complains about low memory. From the logs

> Scan progress is slowing due to JVM garbage collection, which may
>   indicate low memory. For details on making more memory available,
>   please consult the user manual.
>
> [error]: There is not enough memory available to complete analysis. 
>   For details on making more memory available, please consult the user
>   manual.

I have added -Xmx26G and ‑disable‑language javascript in the translation step.

Not sure other optimization can be done ? Any pointers are appreciated. Code base is python, js and php.